# Canceled a order but still shows in my owned item. android inapp purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-pay

I did implement the v3 api of google play in app purchase in my application.
Everything goes right but the strange thing is when i am testing it using my test account and canceled the order from my merchant account. in my app it still shows the item is owned by test user and he is able to use all premium functions.

Any suggestions on how can i get rid of this.

i tried it using complete uninstall and reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you may be seeing is Google Play's device-side cache.  If the user reboots his phone it will clear it, otherwise you must wait for Google Play to update it's cache from the Google Servers.  I have the opposite problem sometimes... user purchases, but for some reason Google Play gets an invalid response from Google's servers and caches a not purchased result for a couple of days.  Rebooting the device, and in severe cases clearing the Google PLay data in the applications list causes Play to resync everything from Google.

Comment: I've also found that Google have some server side caching as well, and a consume call in your app on a bogus order will trigger a cache refresh. Just be sure to remove that bogus call after you've finished testing.

Comment: Clearing Google Play Store's cache (by dragging it from All Apps to App Info > Storage > Clear Cache) fixed the issue for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have bought before by your account and it`s a non-consumable item, when you try again to buy the server will send you a status 'item bought'. (like a restore trasaction)

Else check all fields of the response from server.

Check the responde code:
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html

BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_USER_CANCELED   1   User pressed back or canceled a dialog